# Apply conversion to all elements in a ComboBox drop down menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, multibinding

I am trying to change the text only for contents of all items in a `ComboBox` based on a specific property in the `ViewModel`.  I’ve created a `DataTemplate` with the `Binding` values as `SelectedValue` and the specific property I want to base the conversion on `SomeProperty`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChannelValues}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Channel, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ChannelNumConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedValue" 
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}" />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.SomeProperty"
                     ElementName="DataContextView" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This appears to work, expect all the values in the drop down get changed to the translated `SelectedValue`.  I’ve tried replacing `SelectedValue` with `Text`, but that doesn’t work either.  Is there a way to apply this conversion to all values in the drop down (again, only changing the displayed values, not the underlying data)?

**Update - ViewModel**

```
// Populate somewhere with values
private ObservableCollection<ushort> mChannelValues = new ObservableCollection<ushort>();

public ObservableCollection<ushort> ChannelValues
{
   get
   {
      return mChannelValues;
   }
}

private ushort mChannelNum;
public ushort Channel
{
   get
   {
      return mChannelNum;
   }
   set
   {
      if (mChannelNum != value)
      {
         mChannelNum = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Channel"));
      }
   }
}

private ushort mSomeProperty;
public ushort SomeProperty
{
   get
   {
      return mSomeProperty;
   }
   set
   {
      if (mSomeProperty!= value)
      {
         mSomeProperty= value;
         OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeProperty"));
      }
   }
}
```

**Update 2 - Simple Converter**

```
public object Convert(
   object[] values,
   Type targetType,
   object parameter,
   CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (targetType != typeof(string))
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a string");
   if ((values[0] != null) && (!(values[0] is ushort)))
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The channel must be an short");
   if ((values[1] != null) && (!(values[1] is ushort)))
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The some property must be a ushort");

   ushort ushort_val = ushort.Parse((string)values[0]);
   ushort ushort_some_property = ushort.Parse((string)values[1]);

   switch (ushort_some_property)
   {
      case 0:
         return (ushort_val + 1).ToString();
      case 1:
         return (ushort_val + 7).ToString();
      case 2:
         return (ushort_val + 2).ToString();
      default:
         return ushort_val.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the converter and affected viewmodel code

Comment: @MABVT - The converter would be very basic, just takes in the values and returns the new converted text value.  The ViewModel has a collection of channels `ChannelValues`, the selected channel `Channel` and `SomeProperty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this.  Below is the xaml to apply the converter to all elements in the drop down list:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChannelValues}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Channel, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ChannelNumConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.SomeProperty"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType=local:DataContextView}" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `MultiBinding`, you could use `SomeProperty` as a `ConverterParameter`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ChannelNumConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding SomeProperty}}"/>
```

In converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   var someProperty = parameter as SomeType;
   ...
```

Comment: What would `PropertyInChannelValue` be?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what types you have in ChannelValues. Are they your own custom class, or strings, enum values, etc?

Comment: Update the question with the ViewModel.

Comment: I get the following exception `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in fact that your itemTemplate is applied to **ALL!** Items in the combobox, whose converter actually processes the currently selected item and someproperty leading to equal values in all items.

The approach at this point is not the problem. You just have to bind the current text's value **in the viewmodel**  instead of the selected value.

This will combine two values from your viewmodel into the result displayed in the textbox without any recursive updates.

Comment: If I change it to `<Binding Path=".Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />`, it just recursively calls the converter because the Text is changing.

Comment: Then consider binding to the value in the model immediately (which by the way removes the requirement of a converter entirely since conversion can take place in the viewmodel...)